# How can i insert a string into a dynamic search url, after fetching the string from a form?

Tags: redirect, search, dynamic, url-rewriting

```
<form class="notfound-search" method="post" action="https://something.org/?product_cat=&s=VARIABLE&post_type=product">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
```

I am trying to get the string (to be searched) from the form and after submission, the string will get in place of the VARIABLE and redirects to the new link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the string.replace method to change the url value as below but you need to add some javascript to achieve that and also add id attribute to your elements as below.

```
<form class="notfound-search" method="post" action="https://something.org/?product_cat=&s=VARIABLE&post_type=product" id="search-form">
            <input id="search-text" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
            <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btnSubmit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var url = $('#search-form').prop('action');

        var search = $(#'search-text').val();

        url = url.replace("VARIABLE", search);

        $('#search-form').prop('action', url);

        //or

       $('#search-form').attr('action', url);

        $("#search-form").submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Yaddly,  thanks for your helping approach. but this code didn't work. As i am new to js, maybe i couldn't configure things to be changed. Can you please elaborate the code?

Comment: @PrashantKumarKashyap What language are you using? could you please share a git repo

Comment: the source file was a .html but i had changed it to a .php file. it started working after i changed it back to .html file. But i have to remove the preventDefault(); function from the code and it worked all good.  i was trying to introduce a 404 error page to my wordpress website. and trying to use the website's search url to work taking a input string from the 404 error page's search form.

Comment: Thanks to Stackoverflow Community. Thank You @yaddly

Comment: @PrashantKumarKashyap I'm glad it all worked out for you, please kindly accept the code above as a working solution and upvote it to help the next person looking for a similar answer.